# Change name and logo on Auth0 signup

Tags: auth0

Users get this on new signups on my app:

[image]

On auth0 dashboard I've named my app and uploaded a logo.

Where am I suppose to enter information to show this info on signup dialog?

Comment: Where is your code or a link to the git repository?

Comment: What code do you want to see? Should'nt this be taken care of by auth0?

Comment: where does your screenshot come from? please note more information

Comment: When the user signs up for the first time

Comment: When does the user register for the first time on what? You have not explained the context of your problem. Which application do you use? We do not have any information to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [UI Customization docs](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/ui-customization)

> The value for logo is a URL for an image that will be placed in the Lock's header, and defaults to Auth0's logo. It has a recommended max height of 58px for a better user experience.

```
var options = {
  theme: {
    logo: 'https://example.com/logo.png'
  }
};
```

[image]

Check also the section [Customizing Text](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/ui-customization#customizing-text) to change the name, for example:

```
var options = {
  languageDictionary: {
    emailInputPlaceholder: "something@youremail.com",
    title: "Log me in"
  },
};
```

[image]

For the [sign-up](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration#additionalsignupfields-array-):

```
var options = {
  additionalSignUpFields: [{
    name: "address",
    placeholder: "enter your address",
    // The following properties are optional
    icon: "https://example.com/assests/address_icon.png",
    prefill: "street 123",
    validator: function(address) {
      return {
         valid: address.length >= 10,
         hint: "Must have 10 or more chars" // optional
      };
    }
  },
  {
    name: "full_name",
    placeholder: "Enter your full name"
  }]
}
```

> `additionalSignUpFields` Intended for use with database signup only
>   additionalSignupFields are intended for use with database signups only. If you have social sign ups too, you can ask for the additional information after the users sign up (see this page about custom signup for more details). You can use the databaseAlternativeSignupInstructions i18n key to display these instructions.

For more details check [Custom Signup](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/custom-signup)

If using LinkedIn see this [example](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/linkedin), and also change the text as required:
[image]

Comment: This is the login modal. Not the sign-up modal as in the question.

Comment: @Per Updated the answer with the `additionalSignUpFields `

Comment: I have linkedin auth. The additionalSignUpFields is for database signup only. I need to change the text "Auth0 examples" and the icon.

Comment: @Per check this example: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/linkedin#3-enter-details-about-your-app modify those values and test there you can change the  required text

Comment: Ah there it was. Thank you for your help.